# hide header base on scroll delta not scroll position

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

how I can get scroll change from start to end with `react native flat list` and change the height of header base on that like bellow example

[example-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25nK5.gif)

for instance

```js
const delta = end_scroll_pos - start_scroll_pos; // for example delta = 60
```

for example between scroll postion 220 and 280 delta 60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently developed a new package, **react-native-animated-screen**, that does exactly what you need

Check it out

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-screen

[image]

```js
import  React  from  'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from  'react-native';
import AnimatedScreen from  'react-native-animated-screen';

const  Component = () => {
   const animationStart = 90; 
   const animationEnd = 300; // the header will be totally collapsed by screen scrolled 300
   return (
     <AnimatedScreen.Wrapper>
       <AnimatedScreen.Header headerMinHeight={animationStart} headerMaxHeight={animationEnd}>
         <View>
           <Text>Title</Text>
           <AnimatedScreen.CollapsibleElement>
             <Text>Subtitle</Text>
           </AnimatedScreen.CollapsibleElement>
         </View>
       </AnimatedScreen.Header>
       <AnimatedScreen.ScrollView>
         <View  style={{ height: '300%' }}>
           <View>
             <Text>Body</Text>
           </View>
         </View>
       </AnimatedScreen.ScrollView>
     </AnimatedScreen.Wrapper>
   );
};
```

In the example above only the title is going to remain after scrolling, the subtitle (as all the elements wrapped in a CollapsibleElement) will disappear.
You can use the two params `headerMinHeight` and `headerMaxHeight` of the AnimatedHeader wrapper component to define exactly after how much scroll the animation should start and complete